# Roll 5 dice and see if 3 are the same

Tags: java, loops, random, dice

Full question: Simulates repeated trials to estimate the probability of rolling five dice and obtaining at least three numbers that are the same.

I know how to check for the probability using repeated trials and stuff. I just do not know how to see if three dice out of five will be the same. Important to note: we have not learned arrays yet in my class, so I cannot use that. We have learned objects, decisions, and are currently learning loops. Any help with how to check if three are the same would be appreciated. Here is what I have right now:

```
Random rand = new Random();

    final int TRIALS = 100_000;
    int same = 0;//check if they are the same??

    for(int i=0; i<TRIALS; i++){
        int a = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        int b = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        int c = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        int d = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        int e = rand.nextInt(6)+1;

    }
```

Comment: Do you want the **probability** or check if actually are 3 same numbers and return **true/false**?

Comment: Off shoot of @Thrasher comment. The probability can be found without **actually** rolling the dice and so I await the response to the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this should work for you:

```
        Random rand = new Random();

    final int TRIALS = 100;
    int same = 0;//check if they are the same??
    int aux = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<TRIALS; i++){
        aux = 0;
        int a = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        int b = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        int c = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        int d = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        int e = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        if(a == b || a == c || a == d || a == e)
            aux++;
        if(b == c || b == d || b == e)
            aux++;
        if(c == d || c == e)
            aux++;
        if(d == e)
            aux++;
        if(aux > 2)
            same++;
    }
    System.out.println("The posibilities are: " + same + "/" + TRIALS);
}
```

Trying not to use anything that is out of what you know right now.

You can also try this, is the same but you'll have the exact prob:

```
    final int TRIALS = 100;
    int same = 0;//check if they are the same??
    int aux = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<TRIALS; i++){
        aux = 0;
        int a = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        int b = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        int c = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        int d = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        int e = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        if(a == b || a == c || a == d || a == e)
            aux++;
        if(b == c || b == d || b == e)
            aux++;
        if(c == d || c == e)
            aux++;
        if(d == e)
            aux++;
        if(aux > 2)
            same++;
    }
    double prob = same/TRIALS;
    System.out.println("The posibilities are: " + prob);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I'm doing here is just simulating it 1000 times and rolling 5 dices on each simulation and recording each outcome by incrementing the integer variable that represents that outcome (ie. ones, twos, etc) and at the end, if any of the integers are > 2 (ie. occurred 3+ times out of 5), then I will increment same. Then you can just divide same by 1000 to get the probability.

```
Random rand = new Random();

final int TRIALS = 1000;
int same = 0;//check if they are the same??

for(int i = 0; i < TRIALS; i++){
    int ones = 0;
    int twos = 0;
    int threes = 0;
    int fours = 0;
    int fives = 0;
    int sixes = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        int curr = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        if (curr == 1) {
            ones++;  
        } else if (curr == 2) {
            twos++; 
        } else if (curr == 3) {
            threes++;
        } else if (curr == 4) {
            fours++;
        } else if (curr == 5) {
            fives++;
        } else if (curr == 6) {
            sixes++;
        }
    }
    if (ones > 2 || twos >= 2 || threes >= 2 || fours > 2 || fives > 2 || sixes > 2) {
        same++;
    }
}

double probability = (double)same/TRIALS;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Scenario:

> Dice **five rolls** certain times and calculate the estimated probability of getting **at least** 3 numbers equals (4 and five inclusive) with the results.

### Flowchart:

I created a flowchart so you can understand what is being calculated.

[image: Flowchat diagram]

### Code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RollDices
{
    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int threeEquals=0;
        int notThreeEquals=0;
        final int TRIALS = 567;


        int dice = 0; 

        int one = 0;
        int two = 0;
        int three = 0;
        int four = 0;
        int five = 0;
        int six = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<TRIALS; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {

                dice = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
                if(dice == 1) one++;
                if(dice == 2) two++;
                if(dice == 3) three++;
                if(dice == 4) four++;
                if(dice == 5) five++;
                if(dice == 6) six++;

            }


            if( one >= 3 ||
                    two >= 3 ||
                    three >= 3 ||
                    four >= 3 ||
                    five >= 3 ||
                    six >= 3)
            {
                System.out.println ( "Yay! one number is repeated at least 3 times" );
                System.out.println ( "[" + one + "," + two +","+ three +","+ four +","+ five +","+ six +"]");
                threeEquals++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println ( "No number is repeated 3 times" );
                System.out.println ( "[" + one + "," + two +","+ three +","+ four +","+ five +","+ six +"]");
                notThreeEquals++;
            }


           one = 0;
           two = 0;
           three = 0;
           four = 0;
           five = 0;
           six = 0;
        }
        System.out.println ( "At least three equals count: " + threeEquals );
        System.out.println ( "Less than three equals count: " + notThreeEquals );
        System.out.println ( "Trials: " + TRIALS );
        System.out.println ( "Estimated probability: " + ((double)threeEquals/TRIALS)*100 + "%");

    }
}
```

### Output:

No number is repeated 3 times

> ...
>   [0,0,1,2,1,1]
>
> No number is repeated 3 times
>
> [1,0,1,0,1,2]
>
> Yay! one number is repeated at least 3 times
>
> [0,1,0,0,3,1]
>
> Yay! one number is repeated at least 3 times
>
> [0,0,2,3,0,0]
>
> At least three equals count: 119
>
> Less than three equals count: 448
>
> Trials: 567
>
> Estimated probability: 20.98765432098765%

---

### Extra:

You can calculate probability without rolling the dices. You need to ask "What is the probability that none of them happen?" and subtract from 1 (since the complementary event to "none happen" is "at least one happens").

I checked all the possibilities within 5 roll dices and counted which of them have 3 or more repeated numbers, resulting in:

The probability of 3 equals: [image]

The probability of 3 not equals: [image]

In conclusion, the final formula is:   [image]

### Example:

With the above formula:

[image]

As you can see, with every attemp of 5 roll dice your probabilities of getting at least three equal numbers rise a lot.